# How to change max_length of a field on a proxy model in Django

Tags: python, django

I am working on a bulletin board project. I have two Django model classes:

```
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
...

class Bulletin(models.Model):
    # other fields...
    content = RichTextField('Content (Don\'t use this and content image)',
                            max_length=5000, blank=True,
                            null=True) 

# other classes...

class QuoteManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(QuoteManager, self).get_queryset().filter(
            bulletin_type=BulletinType.QUOTE.name)

class Quote(Bulletin):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    objects = QuoteManager()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.bulletin_type = BulletinType.QUOTE.name
        super(Quote, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This allows me to keep all my proxy classes in the same DB and have the same fields as my base "Bulletin" class.

What I want to do is modify the Quote proxy class to have a `max_length` of say 200. How can I do this?

**What I've tried?**

I tried adding "content" to the proxy class and this was a name collision.

I tried adding a field called "quote_content" to the proxy class as a workaround, but this also failed as you cannot create fields in proxy classes.

A perfect solution would allow me to keep my proxy class, but still modify the max_length. Is such a think even possible?

Answer (score -1):

You can try using, forms

I don't think proxy model will allow you to do so

Comment: Hey, I'm not sure what you mean by "use forms." Any chance you could ellaborate?